# Command fails to execute in upstart session job

Tags: command-line, upstart, mongodb

This command:

```
mongod --fork --dbpath ../data --smallfiles --logpath ../data/mongo.log
```

runs perfectly from terminal, while in directory `/mongo/bin/`

But, when I use same command and directory for upstart session job file (at `$HOME/.config/upstart`):

```
# mongod_service - mongoDB job file
description "MongoDB service"
author "admin"

# When to start the service
start on runlevel [2345]

# When to stop the service
stop on runlevel [016]

# Automatically restart process if crashed
# respawn

# Essentially lets upstart know the process will detach itself to the background
expect fork

# working directory
chdir /mongo/bin/

# log this job
console log

# Start mongod as daemon
exec /mongo/bin/mongod --fork --dbpath /mongo/data --smallfiles --logpath /mongo/data/mongo.log
```

**Update:**
Changed job file and It starts fine now, but when I try to stop it with `initctl stop mongod-service`, the command never completes !.

Can anyone suggest how to make this work ?

Comment: are you sure you can use relative paths? Also: for debugging see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/36200/how-to-debug-upstart-scripts

Comment: @Rinzwind Replaced with absolute paths, no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you are using a version of MongoDB built from Git, you can still reuse the official upstart config file:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/debian/mongod.upstart

and update it as required.

Comment: Yes, I'm always keeping a latest build from the git clone and configuring custom database paths etc. Also updated question.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect your response.

Comment: Thanks. I'll need to make some edits though.

Comment: Hmmm.. it uses a daemon starter, which is strange because upstart was supposed to be the alternative.