# Failed to start <myapp>.service: Unit <myapp>.service not found

Tags: python, upstart, services, init.d

I created a super basic init.d script for my python bot:

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 2345 20 80
# description: Description comes here....

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

start() {
    echo "starting torbot"
    python /home/ctote/dev/slackbots/torbot/torbot.py
    # example: daemon program_name &
}

stop() {
    # code to stop app comes here
    # example: killproc program_name
}

case "$1" in
    start)
       start
       ;;
    stop)
       stop
       ;;
    restart)
       stop
       start
       ;;
    status)
       # code to check status of app comes here
       # example: status program_name
       ;;
    *)
       echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
esac
```

And have set `torbot.py` to be `+x` and `#!/usr/local/bin/python` at the top. When I try to actually start it though, I get:

`:/var/lock/subsys$ sudo service torbot start
Failed to start torbot.service: Unit torbot.service not found.`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using ubuntu 16.04 or newer you may want to review the doc of systemd about [creating service files](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html)

The script is for the old init system and is managed by a legacy compatibility layer.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Firstly change the init function

```
. /etc/init.d/functions
```

to

```
. /lib/lsb/init-functions
```

Then in shell, create symbolic links from /etc/rc* to my script:

```
sudo update-rc.d <myapp> defaults 95
```

Comment: What means 95 here?

Comment: @Gherman it's priority

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I tried some steps this stackoverflow answer([Running upstart script on 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930589/running-upstart-script-on-17-04)) and they worked
My env is as follows

1. Ubuntu at 17.10
2. I have a python app on Gunicorn 19.x server, I need to start this application as a service.

Firstly you need to write a foo.service file.

```
[Unit] 
Description=FooServer 

[Service] 
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/your/working/directory/where the foo lives
ExecStart=/what/process/will call foo eg: in my case I used gunicorn app:app
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID 
KillSignal=SIGINT 

[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The meaning of every word on the left hand side of the '=' sign and their equivalent in (to the earlier) upstart is in link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers

Once the file is ready, let's say you name it as 'foo.service' (the .service extension is important)

You need to place the file in `/lib/systemd/system`

After which you need to enable the service by calling

```
systemctl enable foo
```

Which will prompt you enter your root password as it will be creating symlinks.

If you have reached till here without any hassle , you are good.
Your service is hence created 
Start is by calling

```
sudo service foo start
```

`systemctl status foo` to see the status
`sudo service foo stop` to stop the service

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired something like this? [How do I debug Upstart scripts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36200/how-do-i-debug-upstart-scripts)

Can you provide the output to that this guide provides so that we can help you potentially debug your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, this is the solution that worked for me. Try:

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl enable daemon_app.service

sudo systemctl start daemon_app.service