# Run script at login when GUI is ready with Kubuntu 17.10

Tags: command-line, scripts, kubuntu, startup, upstart

I have found many things on how to do that.

I tried with upstart, but it didn't do anything. I think I found [some post](https://askubuntu.com/a/930788/811976) that tells it doesn't come out of the box with upstart anymore. This is why this question is not a duplicate of [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up).

I tried using the "Autostart" application, but whenever I add my script there, close the window and reopen it, it's gone.

I would like to execute a bash script when my user is logged in and the GUI is ready (because the script is going to open and set-up some applications). What is the best way (preferably through command line) to achieve that?

Comment: By "using the "Autostart" application", do you mean the interface you get via System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Automatically started applications? That should work! Kubuntu stores the information you provide in `~/.config/autostart` and `~/.config/autostart-scripts`. To make sure the GUI is ready, you may need to add a `sleep` value at the start of your script.

Comment: My script is called .bash_startup and is located in my home directory. I tried adding it as a "script" in Autostart, but it kept telling me that by doing that, I would replace the script file with itself. I didn't understand why so I added it as an "Application". Now, I have a file .config/autostart/.bash_startup.desktop which has the information about my script. Still, the script doesn't seem to be loaded.

Comment: 1) If your script is small, add it to your question. 2) Have you made it executable? 3) If you're sure the script works and doesn't need a preliminary `sleep`, just copy the script over to `~/.config/autostart-scripts`, log out and log back in. Maybe that'll work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

Comment: … the approach explained in [muru's answer there](https://askubuntu.com/a/719157/507051) should work fine in Kubuntu 17.10.

Comment: I suggest to wait for the main process of your desktop environment with a `while` loop, e.g. with `while [[ ! $(pgrep plasmashell) ]]; do sleep 1; done` which tests every second (at least in Kubuntu 16.04 the process is called `plasmashell`, adapt it if necessary).

Comment: @dessert I think it would be reasonable, and helpful, to write a specific answer here, whether or not reviewers decide to close the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed DK Bose's and dessert's advice and came up with this script located in `~/.config/autostart-scripts/`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Wait for the GUI to be ready
while [[ ! $(pgrep plasmashell) ]]; do sleep 1; done

# Do what I want
```

And it works well!